# Is there a reverse method for MooTools toElement()?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm happily using MooTool's toElement(), which is able to keep track of which DOM-element belongs to a certain instance of my class. Is there a way to reverse this behavior? As in: give it an element and get a reference to the instance of the class it belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

You can store and retrieve an object reference on a DOM element using [**`Element.store()`**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3astore) and [**`Element.retrieve()`**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aretrieve) methods.

You class could be for example:

```
var MyClass = new Class({

    initialize: function(element) {
        this.el = document.id(element); // Store element for later usage

        // Store a reference to "this" object on the Element itself
        this.el.store('_MyClass', this);

        return this;

    },

    // Object -> Element (you already know this)
    toElement: function() {
        return this.el;
    }

});

// The following implements a new property for all Elements (optional)
Element.Properties.myClass = {

    get: function() {
        return this.retrieve('_MyClass');
    }

};
```

And then, to retrieve the object instance attached to the DOM element:

```
// Object creation
new MyClass($('some_element'));

// The easy way, if you did not implemented Element property
var myClassInstance = $('some_element').retrieve('_MyClass');

// Or prettier, if you implemented property like I showed you
var myClassInstance = $('some_element').get('myClass');
```

Comment: yep, only i'd do `return this.el.store('myclass', this);` so it only exports it if it's being used by a `new MyClass().inject(document.body);`